# Change default URL example.com/new_page to example.com/new_page/username in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When a new user signs up, I set the new page jump to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/email_confirm`, but now I want to change the URL to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/email_confirm/username`. That is, I want to add `username` to the default URL. How can I rewrite the code?

I use  Rails 4.2.8 and Ruby 2.5.0.

The `controllers/user_controller.rb` code is:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)  
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "almost success!"
      redirect_to :email_confirm
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'fail to signup！'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

The `routes.rb` code is:

```
get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
get 'login'   => 'sessions#new'
get 'profile' => 'users/show'
get 'email_confirm' => 'users#email_confirm'
post 'login'   => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
resources :users
```

And `email_confirm.html.erb` is in `app/views/users/email_confirm.html.erb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `routes.rb`, change:

```
get 'email_confirm' => 'users#email_confirm'
```

to:

```
get 'email_confirm/:username' => 'users#email_confirm', as: 'confirmation'
```

Then, once the user signs up successfully, `redirect_to confirmation_path(@user.username)`

Comment: thanks very much ,with my best bless. I just change a little:`redirect_to confirmation_path(@user.name)`  , then it works as my except. Thanks a lot .

Comment: Glad it helped.