# rails4 add friendly_id has wrong undefined method `slug' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I used rails4.2.8, ruby2.5.0, 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'

when I gem the `friendly_id` to the Gemfile,

first: `bundle`
second: `rake db:migrate`
third:  in `models/user.rb`  add

```
extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

in `controllers/user_controller.rb` change as follows:

```
def show
    # @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    # debugger
  end
```

and then I `rails s` and creat new users , it display a wrong:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `slug' for #<User:0x00007f89fb2d7508>

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params) 
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "signup success~"
      redirect_to @user
```

I had search this wrong in stackoverflow , someone said change `models/user.rb`  as

```
 extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => [:slugged, :finders]
```

I had try this answer ,but it also displays the wrong as this:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `slug' for #<User:0x00007f89fb2d7508>
```

How can I to solve this questions?  thanks for your help so much~~~

Comment: you need to add the column `:slug` to your user table

Comment: @sovalina Thanks for your help ,how should  I add the columm `:slug` to my user table ? could you show me the codes? Thanks so much~~

Comment: check @a3y3 answer :)

Comment: OK，thank you so much also...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a slug column to your users table through a migration. Create a new migration:
`rails g migration addSlugToUsers`

then add:

```
add_column :users, :slug, :string 
add_index :users, :slug, unique: true
```

to `db/migrate/xxxx.add_slug_to_users.rb`

And run: `rails db:migrate`

Comment: Hi @a3y3 , thanks for your help , it works good.  And then , could you help me to answer other question if you have time? The url is :`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114586/rails4-change-default-url-xxx-com-new-page-to-xxx-com-new-page-username`, I couldn't solve this questions either, for I'm the beginner for rails.